# Having trouble with plot and vcat inside a Julia script

Tags: julia

I must be doing something wrong. I have a Julia script (below) that uses both `vcat` and `plot`. When I run the script, `vcat` returns an empty DataFrame. Another function calls `plot` and no plot is generated.

When I manually type the commands in the terminal window the commands behave normally.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
f_l = file_list[start_row_num:end_row_num] # Build a dataframe containing the data
len = length(f_l)
tmp_stock_df = DataFrame(CSV.File(f_l[1]))
vcat(s_d_df, tmp_stock_df)
println(s_d_df)
for i = 2:len
    tmp_stock_df = DataFrame(CSV.File(f_l[i]))
    tmp_stock_df.quote_datetime = map((x) -> DateTime(x, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"), tmp_stock_df.quote_datetime)
    DataFrames.vcat(s_d_df, tmp_stock_df)
end
```

Comment: "I have a Julia script" - please show it or a [mcve] if it's too long

Comment: f_l = file_list[start_row_num:end_row_num]

        # Build a dataframe containing the data
        len = length(f_l)
        tmp_stock_df = DataFrame(CSV.File(f_l[1]))
        vcat(s_d_df, tmp_stock_df)
        println(s_d_df)
        for i = 2:len
            tmp_stock_df = DataFrame(CSV.File(f_l[i]))
            tmp_stock_df.quote_datetime = map((x) -> DateTime(x, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"), tmp_stock_df.quote_datetime)

            DataFrames.vcat(s_d_df, tmp_stock_df)
        end
The routine reads files from a directory and creates a large dataframe.

Comment: Please include this code _in the post_ and `format it properly`

Comment: My guess is that the working directory of your script is not the same as when you are running it in the terminal. Try using `pwd()` and `cd("path/to/files")` in your script to make sure it is accessing the correct file location.

Comment: Nathan, Thanks for your reply.Unfortunately the path is correct. When I look at the tmp_stock_df dataframe it contains the contents of the last file read but the destination dataframe contains 0 rows.

Comment: The next step in debugging would be to figure out which line or statement in your script is not behaving as you expect. Does `println(s_d_df)` output what you expect on the 5th line? If you replace line 6 with `i=2`, comment out the `end` line with `#`, and `println(s_d_df)` again at the bottom, does it look correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what you're doing differently when manually typing in the commands, but it seems to me that this code would ever produce the results you're looking for. Apart from the fact that `s_d_df` is not defined, `vcat` does not mutate its arguments, and therefore you're never actually adding to your DataFrame:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df1 = DataFrame(a = rand(2), b = rand(2)); df2 = DataFrame(a = rand(2), b = rand(2));

julia> vcat(df1, df2)
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a         b        
     │ Float64   Float64  
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 0.918298  0.343344 
   2 │ 0.538763  0.188229 
   3 │ 0.347177  0.385166 
   4 │ 0.18795   0.98408  

julia> df1
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a         b        
     │ Float64   Float64  
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 0.918298  0.343344
   2 │ 0.538763  0.188229
```

You probably want `s_d_df = vcat(s_d_df, tmp_stock_df)` to assign the result of the concatenation.

On a related note, it looks like you just have a list of files `f_l` with different csv files stored on your system which you want to read into a single DataFrame, in which case you can just replace the whole loop with:

```
s_d_df = vcat(CSV.read.(f_l, DataFrame)...)
```

(potentially also use the `dateformat = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"` kwarg in `CSV.read` to directly parse the dates when reading in the file).